# Website using wrong URL after proxing though Nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

This is my first time using nginx and I'm finding this situation quite puzzling. My website is hosted at `web.example.com` and in order to reach the backend, requests are routed though nginx as a reverse proxy. After processing through nginx, the URL changes to the URL of the nginx server (`proxy.example.com`) instead of being the URL of the website.

The flow looks something like this:

web.example.com -> nginx (proxy.example.com) -> backend (service.example.com)

When I log the request in the backend service, I can see that the x-forwarded-host is set to `proxy.example.com`. Is this correct or should it be set to `web.example.com` here?

The nginx.conf file is:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include    /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
        '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log   logs/access.log  main;

    server { # simple reverse-proxy
        listen       80;
        server_name  proxy.example.com;

        location /site {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header x-forwarded-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header x-forwarded-host $host;
            proxy_set_header x-forwarded-server $host;
            proxy_set_header x-real-ip $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;
            proxy_pass http://service.example.com$request_uri;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get the URL to go back to `web.example.com/site` after going through this flow instead of showing as `proxy.example.com/site`?

Thanks.

Comment: This configuration looks correct. Exactly what are you seeing that is a problem? Be specific.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the problem is that the proxy's URL is exposed. Why is that happening? I want the URL to remain web.example.com.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The vague description is useless.

Comment: The URL in the location bar of the browser changes from web.example.com to proxy.example.com so the end users can see the URL of the proxy. I don't think that's supposed to happen

Comment: OK, now I get it. That isn't caused by nginx though; that's your backend.

Comment: @MichaelHampton can you say more? How would my backend change the URL in the location bar?

Comment: There's no way any of us can know; it's your backend and you have said nothing about what it is.

Comment: Backend is a java application running on Tomcat 9. I'm logging the headers that come into that application and see the x-forward-* headers set to `proxy.example.com`

Comment: What header? Again, be specific.

Comment: x-forward-host and x-forward-for are both set to proxy.example.com

Comment: That doesn't correspond to the nginx configuration you have shown. What else is in this stack? This time, tell us everything and don't leave out relevant details.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes, I added a few more headers in debugging.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your stack? You say that you have a website at `web.example.com` and you use an nginx as a reverse proxy to `service.example.com` so, it's your web served by the nginx server and context `/site` is proxied to the backend or do you have a previous element prior to that nginx? If you do not have it, why the nginx server is called internally `proxy.example.com` instead of `web.example.com`?